# Postfix - bounce messages are not sent to postmaster

Tags: postfix, email-bounces

I ban and reject some spammer domains/IPs, via:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/client_checks, ...
```

client_checks file:

```
/\@domain\./  REJECT
```

and it works fine, but I want to receive notification on postmaster or special email (bounce@example.com) every time the email is rejected and Delivery failure message is sent to sender(spammer).

I set up the following already in main.cf, but it doesn't work:

```
notify_classes = bounce
bounce_notice_recipient = bounce@example.com
```

Please, could you help me find out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the [notify_classes](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#notify_classes) parameter, to get notified about rejected emails.You may add the `policy` option to get notified about policy rejected mails. The options are explained here:

> notify_classes (default: resource, software)
>
> The list of error classes that are reported to the postmaster. The default is to report only the most serious problems. The paranoid may
>   wish to turn on the policy (UCE and mail relaying) and protocol error
>   (broken mail software) reports.
>
> NOTE: postmaster notifications may contain confidential information such as SASL passwords or message content. It is the
>   system administrator's responsibility to treat such information with
>   care.
>
> The error classes are:
>
> **bounce** (also implies 2bounce)
>
> Send the postmaster copies of the headers of bounced mail, and send 
>   transcripts of SMTP sessions when Postfix rejects mail. The
>   notification is sent to the address specified with the
>   bounce_notice_recipient configuration parameter (default: postmaster).
>
> 2bounce
>
> Send undeliverable bounced mail to the postmaster. The notification is sent to the address specified with the 2bounce_notice_recipient configuration parameter (default: postmaster).
>
> data
>
> Send the postmaster a transcript of the SMTP session with an error because a critical data file was unavailable. The notification
>   is sent to the address specified with the error_notice_recipient
>   configuration parameter (default: postmaster).
>           This feature is available in Postfix 2.9 and later.
>
> delay
>
> Send the postmaster copies of the headers of delayed mail (see 
>   delay_warning_time). The notification is sent to the address specified
>   with the delay_notice_recipient configuration parameter (default:
>   postmaster).
>
> **policy**
>
> Send the postmaster a transcript of the SMTP session when a client 
>   request was rejected because of (UCE) policy. The notification
>   is sent to the address specified with the error_notice_recipient
>   configuration parameter (default: postmaster).
>
> protocol
>
> Send the postmaster a transcript of the SMTP session in case of client or > server protocol errors. The notification is sent to the
>   address specified with the error_notice_recipient configuration
>   parameter (default: postmaster).
>
> resource
>
> Inform the postmaster of mail not delivered due to resource problems. The > notification is sent to the address specified with the
>   error_notice_recipient configuration parameter (default: postmaster).
>
> software
>
> Inform the postmaster of mail not delivered due to software problems. The > notification is sent to the address specified with the
>   error_notice_recipient configuration parameter (default: postmaster).
>
> ```
> Examples:
>
> notify_classes = bounce, delay, policy, protocol, resource, software
> notify_classes = 2bounce, resource, software
> ```

Comment: sorry my typing mistake, of course it is:

    notify_classes = bounce, delay, policy, protocol, resource, software

but it is still doesn't work

Comment: @cmpt, Well, may be you can try adding `policy` to `notify_classes` and `error_notice_recipient = bounce@example.com` to see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, the right setting works is: notify_classes = policy thanks to all, the case is closed

Comment: Just to explain what is happening: With your usage of `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` you REJECT mails and no bounce is generated on your system. (Which is absolutely the right configuration, btw.)

Comment: no, bounce is generated now by:

    bounce_notice_recipient = bounce@example.com